# Adding "require_entry" gives no results

Tags: channel-entries, 404

I have the following simple EE query:

```
    {exp:channel:entries
    channel="australia"
    url_title="{segment_2}"
    limit="1"
    dynamic="no"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
}
```

This code works fine. I now want to harden this code for better 404 management, so I added "require_entry" like so:

```
    {exp:channel:entries
    channel="australia"
    url_title="{segment_2}"
    limit="1"
    require_entry="yes"
    dynamic="no"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
}
```

But now the query does not return any results. I'm lost as to why.
'Enable Strict URLs' is set to 'Yes'.

I've tried eliminating the other parameters, but they don't change the result.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: My gut feeling is that its related to not letting the tag run dynamically. Any reason you're forcing things instead?

Comment: @MIchael: I've got a routing file that embeds the appropriate template, eg. for the above code: {if segment_2 != '' AND segment_3 == ''}{embed="australia/_state"}{/if}  - plus two other cases.